# Number 0 is not saving to database as a prefix in SQL Server of CHAR data type column

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to insert an value as `'019393'` into a table with a `CHAR(10)` column.

It is inserting only `'19393'` into the database

I am implementing this feature in a stored procedure, doing some manipulation like incrementing that number by 15 and saving it back with `'0'` as the prefix

I am using SQL Server database

Note: I tried CASTING that value as VARCHAR before saving to the database, but even that did not get the solution

Code

```
SELECT 
    @fromBSB = fromBSB, @toBSB = toBSB, @type = Type
FROM
    [dbo].[tbl_REF_SpecialBSBRanges]
WHERE
    CAST(@inputFromBSB AS INT) BETWEEN fromBSB AND toBSB

SET @RETURNVALUE =   @fromBSB

IF(@fromBSB = @inputFromBSB)
BEGIN

    PRINT 'Starting Number is Equal';

    DELETE FROM tbl_REF_SpecialBSBRanges 
    WHERE Type = @type AND fromBSB = @fromBSB AND toBSB = @toBSB

    INSERT INTO [tbl_REF_SpecialBSBRanges] ([Type], [fromBSB], [toBSB])
    VALUES(@type, CAST('0' + @fromBSB + 1 AS CHAR), @toBSB)

    INSERT INTO [tbl_REF_SpecialBSBRanges] ([Type], [fromBSB], [toBSB])
    VALUES(@inputBSBName, @inputFromBSB, @inputToBSB)
END
```

Comment: Please post some code... Also, is this mysql or sql-server?  You have both of these tags...

Comment: You need to show the code that you are using. SQL would take this as a char and not char about the 0. However, my guess is that you have code that is truncating this somewhere before it goes to sql

Comment: But I'll take a stab in the dark... It sounds like you may be trying to add '0' to the front of a number, and it's doing integer arithmetic rather than concatenating strings...

Comment: @appclay I removed the mysql tag since the OP directly said SQL Server in the question

Comment: Looks like the datatypes of the `fromBSB` and `toBSB` columns might be integers, given the cast to `int` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem - inserting works just fine, retrieving the CHAR column back shows `019393` ..... there must be something else going on here.... which **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using?? (2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2)

Comment: Also just as a safety tip: you should always define a length when doing a cast - instead of `CAST(@fromBSB AS CHAR)` (*what is the max. length of that CHAR type again??*) you should use `CAST(@fromBSB AS CHAR(10))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, without knowing the column datatypes, I would suggest trying this:

Change from

```
CAST('0'+@fromBSB+1 AS CHAR)
```

To

```
'0'+CAST(@fromBSB+1 AS CHAR(10))
```

But if the columns are integers this won't make a difference.

Comment: And I would suggest to use `'0' + CAST(@fromBSB + 1 AS CHAR(10))` - explicitly specify the length! Just to be safe and clear....

Comment: Added in the char(10) suggestion from @marc_s